# How to find unique values from array with number of duplicates in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array with domain names without www in JavaScript. This array may contain duplicate records. I want to find all unique domains and their occurrence counts. Plz Help.

Here is the current code

```
exports.findUniqueDomains = function(uri_arr){
    uri_arr.forEach(function(elem, index, arr){
        arr[index] = elem.split('.')
            .slice(-2)
            .join('.');
    });

    return uri_arr.filter (function (v, i, a) { return a.indexOf (v) == i });
};
```

Comment: What do you need help with? Just loop over the array and find what you need.

Comment: Did you already try something? What was the problem with your approach?

Comment: Can I do something with my existing function to get the result?

Comment: The first part of your code removes the `www.` from your domain. So replacing the second part with  the answer of the linked question would allow you create two arrays one without duplicates and one with their occurrence. So what is missing to solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

1. Make an object for keeping the values
2. Iterate through the array, each time inserting new entry / incrementing counter in the counting object

For iteration, you can use `for...in`, `.forEach` or some other method.